# Can't access anything on AWS despite being root

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services

I was trying to create an Oracle Database instance in AWS using RDS , then I stumbled upon this error
[image]

Then I was trying to check my account information , and the same access denied is everywhere . I literally can't do anything . I am currently logged in as root user . I am very new to AWS . So any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are logged in as the [AWS account root user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html)? Root users have unrestricted access.

Comment: You are not logged in as root user. You need to talk to your admin.

Comment: Is the account part of an organisation?

Answer (score 0):

your account doesnt have full access to all the resources. it has limited rights to create/remove/use resources in AWS. you need to speak to your admin to get the necessary grants. or if its sub account, then you need to switch the role from top right corner of console to proper role.